# Andengine - Shooting bullets in front of rotating gun

Tags: android, andengine

Hello I searched in the forum,but coudn't find a helpful answer.
I'm making a game with AndEngine and I'm stuck for 3 days on shooting from rotating sprite.

That is my code and how I rotate the gun.I tried here to shoot a bullet ,but it shoots from a wrong starting point I would want to shoot a bullet from the end of the gun.

```java
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()){
          final float dX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - machine.getX();
          final float dY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - machine.getY();

        float angle = (float) Math.atan2(dX,dY);

        float rotation = MathUtils.radToDeg(angle) + 1;

        machine.setRotation(rotation - 90);

        Log.d("BUG",machine.getRotation() + "");
        if(machine.getRotation() >= 84  ){
            machine.setRotation(84);

        }
        if(machine.getRotation() <= -54 ){
            machine.setRotation(-54);


        }

        final int incrementXValue = 15;
        long sElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastFire;

        if(bulletsAmout > 0 && sElapsed > cooldownBetweenShoot * cdModd){

             e = new Entity(0,machine.getY());
             e.setRotation(getRotation());

             SceneManager.getInstance().getCurrentScene().attachChild(e);


                float x2 =  (float) (machine.getSceneCenterCoordinates()[0] + machine.getWidth() /2 * Math.cos(machine.getRotation()));
                float y2 = (float) (machine.getSceneCenterCoordinates()[1]  + machine.getWidth() /2 * Math.sin(machine.getRotation()));

                float realX = (float) (Math.toRadians(x2) + machine.getWidth());
                 realY = (float) Math.toRadians(y2);


            bullets = new Sprite(realX,realY, resourcesManager.bulletRegion.deepCopy(), vbom){
                protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
                    float currentX = this.getX();
                    this.setX(currentX + incrementXValue);
                    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

                }
            };
            bullets.setScale(0.06f);


            e.attachChild(bullets);
            projectilesToBeAdded.add(bullets);
            bulletsAmout--;
            lastFire = System.currentTimeMillis();
            setBulletsText(bulletsAmout);
            resourcesManager.pistolSound.play();


        }

        return true;
    }


    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found how to fix that.

The problem is in this line of code :

```java
    e = new Entity(0,machine.getY());
```

Should be :

```java
     e = new Entity(machine.getX() - (machine.getHeight() / 2),machine.getY())
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are accepting your own answer and not mine. I've listed all possible origins of your problem. However in the end it's up to you...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using GLES2-AnchorCenter:

1. You can position the bullet by setting it to the position of the end of the gun that you can get by calling `gun.convertLocalToSceneCoordinates(gunMuzzleX, gunMuzzleY)`.
2. Then set the bullets rotation to the rotation of the gun.
3. apply velocity to the bullet. Calculate the speed-vector as follows `FloatMath.sin(rotationOfBulletInRadians) * speed` and `FloatMath.cos(rotationOfBulletInRadians) * speed`. 
   **Be aware that you have to pass the rotation in radians to the sin and cos function NOT in degrees!**

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply ,but I have some questions,how to get gunMuzzleX and gunMuzzleY ?
2.I think this should work bullets.setRotation(gun.getRotation());
3. how to get the rotation of the bullet in radians and why you use speed

Comment: And one more question after I have gunMuzzleX and gunMuzzleY how to use it in my code?

Comment: I also tried this ,but not working :        ps.setVelocity(FloatMath.sin((float) Math.toRadians(bullets.getRotation())) * 100,FloatMath.cos((float) Math.toRadians(bullets.getRotation())) * 100);

bullets.registerUpdateHandler(ps);


I rotate the gun and I dont know how to set the starting point of the bullet on the end of the gun..